# Call to plt.subplot() resets subplot size

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm new to matplotlib, so please excuse my noob question. This code works nice:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, 
                       gridspec_kw={
                           'width_ratios': [2, 1],
                           'height_ratios': [1, 2]})

ax[0][0].plot(range(5), range(5, 10))
ax[0][1].plot(range(5), range(10, 5, -1))
ax[1][0].plot(range(5), range(5, 10))
ax[1][1].plot(range(5), range(10, 5, -1))
```

However, if I call `plt.subplot(221)` the ratio defined with `gridspec_kw` is lost: the subplot is redrawn on the upper left quarter of the figure (and the third subplot disappears).

Can you explain what is happening and how I can get a reference to the subplots without losing the ratios?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `plt.subplot(221)` you create a new subplot in the upper left position of a 2x2 grid (221).
As specified in the notes of `plt.subplot()`:

```
Creating a subplot will delete any pre-existing subplot that overlaps 
with it beyond sharing a boundary
```

I am unsure what you precisely mean with

> how I can get a reference to the subplots

You get access to the corresponding axes through `ax[i, j]` as in your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for trying a first answer. My understanding of 'plt.subplot' may indeed be faulty, but I understood that if a subplot already exists at this location, it is not replaced, but all subsequent call to plt will refer to this subplot. Can you confirm that it's wrong?

My original need was just to add an axis label, but with 'ax[0][0].xlabel', I'm getting: AxesSubplot object has no attribute xlabel

So basically, I'll be happy with any method to set the xlabel value :-)

Comment: Set_xlabel is what you want.

Comment: WRT to the access tot he existing axes I think the same axes is returned but only if it’s the same size, which in this case it is not.   It regardless you should just use the object oriented API and you’ll be fine